# Is SQLite good if I want to make a cellphone and desktop application application? (Needs network)

Tags: sqlite

I'm going to be making a fun Python project for myself. This is non concurrent. Only me will use this. I would have a desktop version of the app, with the DB on it. And then my phone would have an app that accesses the information on the DB over network and display the data I want.

For most of the SQLite checklist, seems like a perfect fit for a single user super small project. Except the network part is confusing. Some say no, or yes it's doable but not great. What's the consensus here? If I want to access my DB from my phone from anywhere, is SQLite capable? What problems could I run into with this...

Answer (score 0):

You would have to host your DB somewhere accessible from the internet. By doing this, you open it up for attacks should someone get your server address. You can secure this by setting up a VPN from your phone to the PC, this would allows you to run the SQL server as just a local instance only accessed if you're on the VPN. SQL Lite should work just fine under a VPN setup since it won't require the server to have an open connection out to the internet.

As for problems. If you are somewhere where you cannot establish the VPN connection (firewall, port blocked, etc) you will be cut off from your server.

Comment: Okay so it can do network just fine then? (As in similar to client/server DB's). Also regarding the security breach thing, I mean aren't all network based apps at risk of this? Making a VPN seems like a unnecessary hassle. I could protect access via login or something else to the DB

Comment: Are you sure that SQLite will accept anything that is not a local file?

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html   This site goes over the benefits and uses of SQL Lite. While it can accept outside connections Client/Server setup. It's meant to be used more locally.

Comment: @DasNuk That is exactly what I read, and that is why I ended up confused. Seems to imply you can access it via network, but then immediately in the check list says, is your client app and DB network separated? Use Client/Server DB. It's very confusing as to whether or not i'll have complications from it. Every thing else points me to SQLite for the scope of my project, but I can't settle on the network part.

Comment: Based on what I read. If you want to run SQL Lite, you'll want to VPN into the network to use it. If you want the ability to just access it without VPN, MSSQL Server would be your best option. SQL lite is designed to run locally on in the app itself.

Comment: Alright, seems like MySQL is the way to go. However last question as I just thought about this. What if... the phone app has it's own SQLite DB, which just updates/synchronizes with the one on my computer/server? So if I use my app offline, say out of signal range, all my stats and data are local. If I make edits, then it would resync with the server DB when possible of course. Is that a viable alternative more clean alternative? Or might I just go with MySQL and call it a day?

Comment: @Denis That sounds like an almost perfect solution. Run SQL Lite on the phone and setup a sync at like 1am, when you're home and sleeping, to sync with the DB on your server. You get offline functionality and smaller chance of being breached. :)